# What is each value in the 'HOG feature' list indicates?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

When Extracing HOG feature from an image using

```
bin_n = 16 # Number of bins
def hog(img):
  gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
  gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
  mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
  bins = np.int32(bin_n*ang/(2*np.pi))    # quantizing binvalues in (0...16)
  bin_cells = bins[:10,:10], bins[10:,:10], bins[:10,10:], bins[10:,10:]
  mag_cells = mag[:10,:10], mag[10:,:10], mag[:10,10:], mag[10:,10:]
  hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells, mag_cells)]
  hist = np.hstack(hists)     # hist is a 64 bit vector
  return hist
path1='d:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\training-set\\1\\'
listing1 = os.listdir(path1)
for file in listing1:
 img = cv2.imread(path1 + file)
 h=hog(img)
 print h
```

I am getting a long list of lists like

[image]

What is each number in the list indicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One entry in this list gives the sum of magnitudes for all gradients that are in a given cell (a region of your image) and a certain bin (which is decided by the angle of the gradient which is put into on of 16 bins in your example)